# ILogger.BeginScope(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) produces rubbish in ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights, ilogger

I want to add some key-value properties to my log messages.

I believe the way to to this is to pass a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` to `ILogger.BeginScope` for example like this:

```
...
            finally
            {
                IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> tags = LogTagGatherer.GatherLogTags(context);
                using (logger.BeginScope(tags))
                {
                    if (context.Response.StatusCode < 400)
                    {
                        logger.LogTrace($"StatusCode: {context.Response.StatusCode}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.LogWarning($"StatusCode: {context.Response.StatusCode}"); // Error would spam 404s to email logger.
                    }
                }
            }
```

However, in ApplicationInsights it appears as junk.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add some key-value properties to my log messages.
>
> I believe the way to to this is to pass a  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`  to  `ILogger.BeginScope`  for example like this:

Yes, we can pass the key values pair of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` to `ILogger.BeginScope`

I have noticed in your code you are assigning **LogTagGatherer.GatherLogTags(Context)** into **tags**. Make sure before assigning it contains the key value pair.

```
 IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> tags = LogTagGatherer.GatherLogTags(context);
```

By default how we can processed

```
Dictionary<string, object> tags =new Dictionary<string, object>("context", context);
 
using (logger.BeginScope(tags))
{
    if (context.Response.StatusCode < 400)
    {
        ...
        ..
    }
}
```

#### References

- [ILogger begin scope using key value pair](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/)
- [Attaching key value pairs to scope using .net core](https://andrewlock.net/creating-an-extension-method-for-attaching-key-value-pairs-to-scope-state-using-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Your first reference says to use `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` which I am. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing the individual keys and value, but instead seeing "scope" as the key, that means the scope is not of type `IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string,object>>`.

You may try the example from the below doc and see if that helps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-scopes

Comment: So is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` wrong? I swear `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` is what the documentation says. What type should I be using?